# What is the difference between these two String copies C/C++

Tags: c++, string

I wrote a program to copy `strings`. I got *unexpected* output.

**CODE**

```
tper *mem = new tper[MAX_NUM_USERS];
```

and tper looks like

```
typedef struct tper {
    int8  UserId;
    char  *b[MAX_NUM_START_LOC];
} tper;

/* PROBLEM */

strncpy(mem->b[num], sourceIds[num]->source, STRING_SIZE);
strcpy(mem->b[num], sourceIds[num]->source);

mem->b[num] = sourceIds[num]->source;
```

First two copy crashes at `runtime`. Third copy works. I do not understand why? Both are `char *`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: We can't debug these 3 lines of code, there's dozens of things that could cause these to crash. Can you somehow figure out if `mem->b[num]` points to a buffer that is large enough to contain the string you want to copy ?

Comment: Don't use `strncpy` until you've read its documentation carefully and understood what it actually does. It is **not** a "safe" drop-in replacement for `strcpy`.

Comment: @PeteBecker:  I would be stricter: DO NOT USE `strncpy`. Read its documentation carefully and see what it actually does. It is not a "safe" drop-in replacement for `strcpy`, it is cumbersome and error prone, there is always a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your `mem->b[num]` does not point to a buffer that is large enough to hold the string.

Perhaps the `mem->b[num]` pointer isn't initialized at all, or a NULL pointer.

You're responsible for ensuring `mem->b[num]` points to a valid buffer that is big enough to contain the string you want to copy there if you're using strcpy/strncpy - those functions does not "create" a new string, they just copies bytes from one place to another place, and it's up to you to ensure that other place is valid memory where the bytes can be stored.

**strncpy**

> strncpy(mem->b[num], sourceIds[num]->source,STRING_SIZE);

This copies everything, byte by byte, up till the 0 byte from `sourceIds[num]->source` into the buffer that `mem->b[num]` points to.

Then it fills the remaining bytes of `mem->b[num]` up to `STRING_SIZE` with a 0 byte.

Note:

- if `mem->b[num]` doesn't actually have room for at least STRING_SIZE, strncpy will copy data past the end of `mem->b[num]`
- if `sourceIds[num]->source` has exactly `STRING_SIZE` there is no room for
  a 0 byte in `mem->b[num]` and the data in `mem->b[num]` does not end up as an actual string. In such a case you might need to manually truncate the string, otherwise other code that treats it as a string might run past its boundaries. E.g. do:

  mem->b[num][STRING_SIZE - 1] = 0;

**strcpy**

> strcpy(mem->b[num], sourceIds[num]->source);

This copies everything up till and including the 0 byte from `sourceIds[num]->source` into `mem->b[num]`.

- Note: if `mem->b[num]` doesn't actually have room for at least `strlen(sourceIds[num]->source) + 1` , strcpy will copy data past the end of `mem->b[num]`

**Pointer assignment**

```
 mem->b[num]= sourceIds[num]->source;
```

This just assigns `mem->b[num]` to point to the same thing that `sourceIds[num]->source` points to. No part of the string is copied. If you change anything inside the buffer that `sourceIds[num]->source` points to, you'll see the same when using `mem->b[num]` since they both point to the same thing.

Comment: updated question with memory allocation. I cant understand what is wrong

Comment: @user437777 Where is the code that assigns some valid memory to your `mem->b[num]` ? None of your posted lines of code does that.

Comment: tper*mem=new tper[MAX_NUM_USERS]; Do I need to initialize this? I can copy userID but string copy crashes

Comment: @user437777 `mem-b[0]` is the first pointer in your `b` array inside the `struct tper` This pointer is uninitialized, you can't copy anything to the memory where that pointer points. You need to make it point to a valid memory location. e.g. . `for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_START_LOC` ; i++) { mem->b[i] = new char[STRING_SIZE]`; }` (Ofcourse, if you're using C++, you should be using `std::string` instead of manually copying strings like one does in C. But I think you rather need to create a set of smaller and simpler examples so you learn how pointers, C strings and memory allocation works.)

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy` as well as `strncpy` copies byte-by-byte data from source buffer to the destination buffer. Thus, first of all the destination buffer size should be able to fit all the copying data. This of course presumes both buffers point to valid memory regions. At second, the source buffer must be NULL-terminated except you like to copy less bytes than it contains. Please check whether all this in your case is ok.

Comment: I have right size buffer. It crashes. Why third case works?

Comment: I assume `mem->b[num]` is a pointer to a C string. Then this operation just changes the value of the pointer to point to the source string. No data copying is performed in this case.

Comment: thanks. What is prob with first one. copying two char* strings crashes

Comment: In the first case if all buffers are valid and size is ok, please also check that the source string is NULL-terminated if it shorter than STRING_SIZE. Alternatively, please show how it crashes. Perhaps the crash only interferences with this line but is not a direct consequence of it...

Comment: The added code is even worst - it does not have a valid destination buffer - it is NULL! Thus it is logically that it crashes. Returning to your original question, please show the backtrace of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you have done this in sequence

```
tper *mem = new tper[MAX_NUM_USERS];
strncpy(mem->b[num], sourceIds[num]->source, STRING_SIZE);
strcpy(mem->b[num], sourceIds[num]->source);
```

your problem is that allocating `mem` does not set any of the elements of the array `mem->b` to point at anything.   The elements are all uninitialised pointers, so accessing their values (let alone dereferencing them, which is what `strncpy()` and `strcpy()` do) gives undefined behaviour.

If you allocate memory for the element of `mem->b` to point at ....

```
tper *mem = new tper[MAX_NUM_USERS];
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_START_LOC; ++i)
  mem->b[i] = new char[STRING_SIZE];

strncpy(mem->b[num], sourceIds[num]->source, STRING_SIZE);
strcpy(mem->b[num], sourceIds[num]->source);
```

you will find it works if `sourceIDs[num]` is non-NULL, `sourceIds[num]->source` points at the (first element of) an array of `char`, and (for the `strcpy()` call) if `strlen(sourceIds[num]->source) < STRING_SIZE`.
I am assuming that `num` is between `0` and `MAX_NUM_START_LOC-1`.

The reason `mem->b[num] = sourceIds[num]->source` works is because it is (presumably) a simple pointer assignment.    It does not copy a string from `sourceIds[num]->source` to `mem->b[num]`.